# When does it make sense to run Ookla's speedtest as a single-threaded rather than multi-threaded connection?

Tags: connection, speedtest, multi-threaded

Ookla's speedtest gives the option of running their speed test using a single-threaded or multi-threaded connection.

According to [this](https://editorsean.com/articles/speed-test-websites-differ-trust/) source:

> Most large downloads [over the web] and streaming services operate
> over a single connection to the server, so it makes sense to measure
> the throughput available over a single connection. Personally this is
> my preferred test when comparing ISPs even though it may not show what
> the connection is capable of with multiple simultaneous connections.

Why would single-threaded connections be the preferred choice when comparing different ISP speeds? I'm guessing to test the quality of an ISP's connection, right?

Answer (score 0):

Many ISPs prioritise Ookla traffic, completely messing up any attempt at direct comparison. The best you can do is test both methods & average them.

Try [DSLReports](http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest) instead. It does use different metrics & one could claim it's a 'better' objective test - but more importantly, most ISPs seem to have forgotten to prioritise it, so it can be more accurate as a real-world comparison. It will also test for [bufferbloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/).

[image]

Clicking the Results gives a far more comprehensive analysis.

No affiliation.

*As mentioned in comments, don't confuse the naming of 'multi-threading' with that normally associated with CPU threads. This is about multiple simultaneous connections.
Also note that bufferbloat is usually of far greater significance than a flat-out speed test, under real-world conditions.

Comment: OK, but many tests give you the option of picking between a multi-threaded or single-threaded connection. What I'd like to know is when you should pick one over the other. I'd also like to know why someone would want to use a single-threaded connection to compare different ISPs.

Comment: Threading as a local CPU feature is unlikely to affect the network throughput by much, unless your computer is "slow" in comparison to the network hardware.

Comment: @Hannu - Though they use the term 'thread' they're not talking about CPU task threads but multiple simultaneous connections.

Comment: Then the OP needs to be made aware of the difference. Using the same term for more than one feature us unfortunate, even if it is suiting. Maybe add that to your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure there was any confusion anyway. My answer was really a frame challenge. SpeedTest is pretty useless other than to test your last mile.It no longer shows the threading option; it's no longer Flash-based. Such as Test.my also call the tests single- & multi-threading, so it's not like we're going to fix the entire interwebz nomenclature from here… and last of all, bufferbloat is usually a far bigger issue these days, with so many households trying to squeeze everything down wifi rather than use 'proper' ethernet.

Comment: @Hannu - I've added a bit, put more emphasis on bufferbloat too, & updated my DSLReports pic, to better reflect the current status.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and want a better understanding as to how this works. My thinking and this is without confirmation but that use of one thread to connect is what a single device would use when they are say downloading a file they have a one thread like a 2.4 or 5 but only one can be in use for that device on that download..... So it seems testing this would be a real world type thing for you can never hasve more than one connection to a download at one time, RIGHT??
Like I said I am not sure if I am getting this at all right so please explain so I may understand this correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230981)

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1824638/904401 should be a comment rather than an answer. I know - it's annoying that solely those options are allowed, but unlike Wikipedia, there's no discussion section for SU because it's a Q&A archival site rather than a forum.